# SQL Server : generate possible combinations of numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, combinations

I have a total universe of 41 numbers, and I'm trying to generate the possible combinations of 6 digits between these numbers and insert them into a table in SQL Server.

Could anyone give me a help to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: a example can give better understanding.. is it combination of 6 out of 41 and is repeat allowed ?

Comment: the order of the values does not matter, but should not be repeated. For example, a possible combinatorial would be:

1 - 2 - 10 - 21 - 30 - 41

Comment: So as if you were calculating all possible lottery numbers with 6 out of 41 balls?

Comment: exactly, like in lottery

Comment: are 41 letter coming from  any table ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To generate all possible permutations (`41!/(6!*(41-6)!)` is just under 4.5 million) you could use

```
WITH Balls(N)
     AS (SELECT number
         FROM  master..spt_values
         WHERE type='P'
         AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 41)
SELECT *
FROM   Balls B1
       JOIN Balls B2
         ON B2.N > B1.N
       JOIN Balls B3
         ON B3.N > B2.N
       JOIN Balls B4
         ON B4.N > B3.N
       JOIN Balls B5
         ON B5.N > B4.N
       JOIN Balls B6
         ON B6.N > B5.N
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Store the numbers in a table, and use `cross join` six times to match this table with itself.
If numbers cannot repeat, add `where` clauses, or `inner join` with `on` clause like `on t3.num not in (t1.num,t2.num)`

```
drop table #temp
GO
create table #temp (num int identity(1,1), x int)
GO
insert into #temp default values
GO 41

select 
    *
from #temp t1
cross join #temp t2
cross join #temp t3 
-- and so on
```